IPv6 in IPv4 tunnel, free or affordable, but with not too low timeouts
I need a SaaS IPv6 in IPv4 tunnel (for my Linux PC), because our ISP does not provide IPv6. The preferable form of delivery is a VPN.
I ordered for 5.50 EUR the service from https://6project.org but my downloading through the VPN fails every time. I contacted their support to increase timeouts. They didn't reply yet.
What other free or cheap VPN can you recommend, that has enough timeouts to download software packages (without retrying)?
